# GitLab CI: only trigger only merge request & specific branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

I realised that gitlab CI does not seem to allow multiple `refs`. It will only take the first.

E.g., for the instructions below, the `merge_requests` will be ignored, and will trigger whenever the develop branch is updated directly.

```
face-build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:19.03.8
  services:
    - docker:19.03.8-dind
  script:
    - sh some-scripts.sh
  only:
    refs:
      - /^develop$/
      - merge_requests
```

If I swap the `merge_requests` to be before `/^develop$/` it will be triggered for all merge requests.

Is there anyway to set both to be valid?

Comment: Try only without refs. It is possible, but I've never used refs because its an alpha feature, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using GitLab 12.3 or later, try [`rules:if`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rulesif) clause instead of `only`:

```
face-build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:19.03.8
  services:
    - docker:19.03.8-dind
  script:
    - sh some-scripts.sh
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^develop$/'
      when: always
```

Please check [Rules attributes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules-attributes) so you can choose the most appropriat value for `when` (`on_success`, `always`, `delayed` or `never`).